# What should I do to make the code simple?

Tags: javascript

If you look at my code, there are only two differences.
index and function name(startOf, endOf)

I want to make the code simple and simple.

how can...

```
const { searchDate = [], ...params } = getParams() as FormDataType;

const start = moment(searchDate[0]).startOf('day').format('Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
const end = moment(searchDate[1]).endOf('day').format('Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is very easy to read and understand. Anything you do to it to try to remove duplication will probably make it more complex and harder to understand.

The only thing I would do is define the format and period as their own constants to ensure consistency and make them easy to change or inject later. Like so:

```js
const period = "day";
const dateTimeFormat = "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"

const start = moment(searchDate[0]).startOf(period).format(dateTimeFormat);
const end = moment(searchDate[1]).endOf(period).format(dateTimeFormat);
```

**EDIT:** To illustrate my point, here is what the code would look like with all duplication removed:

```js
const [start, end] = searchDate.map((d,i) => moment(d)[i === 0 ? "startOf" : "endOf"]("day").format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const { searchDate = [], ...params } = getParams() as FormDataType;

const start = this.GetFormateDate(0);
const end = this.GetFormateDate(1);

function GetFormateDate(index:number){
  if(index==0){
  return moment(this.searchDate[index]).startOf('day').format('Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  }else{
  return moment(this.searchDate[index]).endOf('day').format('Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  }
  
}
```

Comment: sorry i am do it by mistake now you can check

Comment: Are you sure this simplifies the code and removes the duplication? It looks to me like it's going in the opposite direction. More duplication and more complexity.

Comment: @BillSourour yes you are right. that's my mistake i am apology for that i am correcting my code from you also. thank you friend

Answer (score 1):

So you can make that as a function like as follows

```
const { searchDate = [], ...params } = getParams() as FormDataType;

const start = this.GetFormateDate(this.searchDate[0],true);
const end = this.GetFormateDate(this.searchDate[1],false);

function GetFormateDate(date,isStart=true,format='Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'){
  if(isStart){
      return moment(date).startOf('day').format(format);
  }
  return moment(date).endOf('day').format(format);
}
```